# dplyr Conditional Selection of Columns (drop columns with < n unique values)

Tags: r, select, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to cut out variables from a dataset that meet certain criteria.  Currently I'm using a two step process of summarising and then dropping columns that meet a logical operation on the summary like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(
     date = seq.Date(as.Date("2012-01-01"), length.out = 5, by = 'day'),
     x = rep(1, times = 5), 
     y = 1:5
 )
tmp <- data %>% 
  select(-date) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(length(unique(.))))

tmp <- names(tmp)[tmp<2]
data <- select(data, -one_of(tmp))
rm(tmp)
```

Then repeating the process for sd, mean etc.  I was just wondering if there was a more tidier way of accomplishing this in one pipe set. Also I have a very wide dataframe so this takes a while to run so any ideas for speed would also be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example dataset.

Comment: Seems like a job for `select_if`.  Something like `select_if(data, function(col) n_distinct(col) >= 5)`.  Hard to tell without an example dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current 'tidy' way to do this is using select(where())

```
n <- 4
iris %>% 
  select(where(~length(unique(.x)) > n))
```

[where() docs](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/where.html)